# Ponteiros e matrizes pegando algo não esperado

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, matriz

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int vetor[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    int valor= *(vetor[1] + 1) + **(vetor + 3);
    printf("%d", valor);
}
```

O código acima foi retirado de exercícios teóricos, porém não possuo o gabarito, mas verifiquei que compila e imprime o valor 15. Entretanto minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1. Por que o array foi declarado com o 'subscrito' da linha vazio  `int vetor[][3]` e qual a diferença entre  `int vetor[0][3]`?
2. Entendi que o trecho `vetor[1]+1` retorna o valor 5 do array, mas
   por que o trecho `**(vetor+3)` retorna o valor 10?
3. Por que o ponteiro para ponteiro `**(vetor+3)`
   funciona mas o ponteiro `*(vetor+3)` não funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por que o array foi declarado com o 'subscrito' da linha vazio  int
>   vetor[][3] e qual a diferença entre  int vetor[0][3]?

Nessa linha você está criando uma matriz. Quando você deixa de especificar a quantidade de elementos em um vetor ele é gerado com base na quantidade de elementos que você coloca na inicialização dele. Por exemplo:

```
int v[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Nesse caso o vetor v será gerado com 3 elementos. Já no seu caso, foi definido apenas a quantidade de colunas da matriz. Como na inicialização temos 12 elementos, o programa irá criar uma matriz de 4 linhas por 3 colunas. Seria uma prática melhor definir previamente a quantidade de elementos, dessa maneira:

```
int vetor[4][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}};
```

O código acima deixa claro como a matriz será organizada, além de definir previamente a quantidade de elementos.

> Entendi que o trecho vetor[1]+1 retorna o valor 5 do array, mas por
>   que o trecho **(vetor+3) retorna o valor 10 ?

Vamos analisar primeiramente o caso `*(vetor[1]+1)`. Lembrando que o vetor é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento e os elementos seguintes são armazenados em sequência. Como a variável `vetor` é uma matriz (ou seja, um vetor de vetores) quando se coloca `vetor[1]` é retornado o endereço à linha 1 da matriz (ou seja, o endereço para o elemento 0 da linha 1). Ao adicionar 1 a esse endereço pegamos o endereço do elemento seguinte (elemento 1 da linha 1 da matriz, lembrando que as linhas e colunas são contadas a partir de 0). Ao colocar o * antes de `vetor`, que está armazenando o endereço, pegamos o valor que está armazenado naquele endereço, portanto 5.
Na parte `**(vetor+3)` o que acontece é que pegamos `vetor` (que é um ponteiro para um ponteiro, pois é um vetor de vetores e cada vetor é um ponteiro) e adicionamos 3 a ele. O que acontece então é que pegamos o ponteiro que contém o endereço para `vetor[3]`.
`vetor` é um ponteiro para ponteiro. Então quando você usa `*vetor[3]` você está acessando o conteúdo de v[3], que será um ponteiro, e então acessando o conteúdo desse outro ponteiro.

> Por que o ponteiro para ponteiro **(vetor+3) funciona mas o ponteiro
>   *(vetor+3) não funciona?

Como dito na resposta anterior, `*(vetor+3)` é apenas o endereço para o conteúdo que você quer acessar. Para acessá-lo você deverá usar `**(vetor+3)`.

Answer (score 9):

Primeiro vamos combinar que esse código está potencialmente errado. Ele compila em compiladores ruins ou mal configurados. Eu não tentaria aprender por ele.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

> Por que o *array* foi declarado com o 'subscrito' da linha vazio `int vetor[][1]` e qual a diferença entre `int vetor[0][1]`?

Porque ele pega do tamanho informado no literal logo à frente na atribuição, ele conta que tem 12 e como uma das dimensões é 3 ele adota 4 e usa este número.

Se usar 0 terá um tamanho de 0, não é o que você quer, não faz sentido ter um *array* que cabe 0 elementos. Em bom compilador nem aceitaria.

Desnecessário fazer estas maluquices, melhor escrever um código legível e conforme.

> Entendi que o trecho `vetor[1] + 1` retorna o valor 5 do *array*, mas por que o trecho `**(vetor+3)` retorna o valor 10?

Pelo mesmo motivo que o trecho anterior pegou 4 e somou com 1 (primeiro elemento da segunda dimensão dentro do elemento 1 da primeira dimensão). Ele pegou o primeiro elemento da segunda dimensão dentro do elemento 3 da primeira dimensão, que é 10.

> Por que o ponteiro para ponteiro `**(vetor+3)` funciona mas o ponteiro `*(vetor+3)` não funciona?

Porque você está pegando o valor da segunda dimensão e não da primeira, então há duas [indireções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Este código faz a mesma coisa com os mesmos compromissos e é muito mais legível:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int vetor[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
    printf("%d", vetor[1][0] + 1 + vetor[3][0]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/slpNDh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qinmnqpx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MultiDimentional.c).